# Automatically expand UIView based on content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIView A with background color set and it contains a UIView B which height can change dynamically. When UIView B's height exceed UIView A, is it possible to have UIView A's height automatically match UIView B's?

I've tried using Autosizing, but it seems it is only meant to resize a child view relative to its parent, but not the other way around.

I also know that there is a method called `sizeToFit`, but this needs to be called manually every time the content changes. Is there no other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not fully automatic, you can use [Key Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to listen for changes to the content, and then do your UIView resizing in there.  That prevents haven't to litter your code with code to resize the views everywhere that the content is changed.

For example (assuming you are doing this in a `UIViewController`):

```
// Somewhere when the view is loaded, probably in -(void)viewDidLoad do this:
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"viewA.frame" options:0 context:NULL];

// Then, implement this method
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    // Resize your views, either using sizeToFit, Purple Ninja's method, or another method
}

// Finally, make sure to unregister in dealloc:
- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"viewA.frame"];
    // ...
    [super dealloc];
}
```

See the [NSKeyValueObserving Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more information

Comment: good answer, it helped me. just note that using sizeToFit, as suggested in the comment in observeValueForKeyPath:... requires you to override sizeToFit in the first place, if you are using a subclass of UIView. +1

Answer (score 1):

Every time UIView B's height changes, try this:

```
if(CGRectGetHeight(B.frame)>CGRectGetHeight(A.frame)) {
    A.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetX(A.frame),CGRectGetY(A.frame),CGRectGetWidth(A.frame),CGRectGetHeight(B.frame));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Purple. I know how to resize A manually. I was wondering if there's a way to *not* have to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this code from my running application

```
CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,, 405);
        frame.origin.x=self.ScrollView.frame.size.width *i;
        frame.origin.y=0;


        frame.size=self.ScrollView.frame.size;
        UIImageView *subimg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth );
        subimg.image=[array objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.ScrollView  addSubview:subimg];
        [subimg release];

        self.ScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.ScrollView.frame.size.width*array.count, self.ScrollView.frame.size.height);
           [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Hear scrollview is an scrollview object declared in .h

Hope it will help